# Attempting To Modify XML in SQL Server Using XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I am attempting to add an attribute to a node in an XML column in SQL Server.

```
UPDATE
    TableName
SET Metadata.modify('
    insert attribute MyAttribute{"01b9cd0b-bfed-436f-bc58-57d2fddd9211"}
    into (Root/Collection/Item[@No="360"][1])
')
WHERE
    TableName.Id = 1
```

I get the following error...

> *Msg 2226, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 XQuery
>
>   [TableName.Metadata.modify()]: The target of 'insert' must be a single
>   node, found 'element(Item,xdt:untyped) *'*

But I thought my selection would return a single item, given the `[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid XQuery! (Or possibly me).

You need to place the `[1]` outside of the brackets:

```
into (Root/Collection/Item[@No="360"][1])
```

Should be

```
into (Root/Collection/Item[@No="360"])[1]
```